# Linksys LRT224 config with Comcast Business router

Tags: networking, router

I have a Comcast Wifi router that's working fine for WIFI usage.  Now I want to connect the Linksys LRT 224 router via the WAN port so that I can use an ethernet connection via the ports on the LRT 224.

When I connect an ethernet cable directly to the WAN port of the Comcast router, I can get wired internet - so that works fine. Wifi is also fine. This router has an ip in the 10.x range with DHCP enabled for Wifi clients (I guess all clients).

What doesn't work is connecting the LRT224 to the same WAN port on the cable modem (Wan to Wan),  and I can't get internet on the LRT 224 ports.

First issue, the LRT is 192.168.x - so that is something I guess I need to change.  When I login to the Linksys Admin page to configure settings, I set the IP address to a valid 10.x address - is that correct?

Secondly, what DHCP option should I chose on LRT224 (should I pick DHCP relay, or disable DHCP)..   assuming the Comcast router will assign all IPs (I don't have a preference but predominant usage will be Wifi).

Given I am getting internet from the WAN port, I guess I don't need to setup any PPoE things on the LRT.

Edit:

I am not looking to setup remote access from outside into this network. My idea (which could be wrong) is that Linksys has a firewall that would be useful to have as an added layer of security.

Possible solution (without using the Linksys at all) :
I have a CISCO switch that I could connect to the Comcast router that would allow me access. Is this the way to go, to forget about the LRT224 and setup ethernet directly via the Cisco Switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Possible solution (without using the Linksys at all) : I have a CISCO
>   switch that I could connect to the Comcast router that would allow me
>   access. Is this the way to go, to forget about the LRT224 and setup
>   ethernet directly via the Cisco Switch.

Bingo.

Rather than get into the technical reasons why, I am going to get straight to the point and answer your question.

Yes, using a switch is what you are supposed to do in this situation.

Everything you are asking and describing that you want to do with the router is the responsibility of a switch. What you are trying to do is make your router a switch. But routers don’t work that way. So, just use the switch.

Comment: Yes, that worked like a charm. On the Comcast router there's a firewall (can't trust it too much).  On my laptop there's a firewall.  Do I need a firewall appliance for all my ethernet clients?

Comment: @blispr that is a question not easily answered and is primarily opinion based. It’s not about trust. It’s technically impossible for ANY internet based system to touch ANY internal private system unless you deliberately port forward to it. So, do you need a firewall? Answer is no if all you’re trying to do is protect internal computers from external computers. If you want to block internal computers from accessing external internet hosts then yes, you need some type of firewall to do that. Adding the linksys router provides zero extra protection out of the box.